# which number stands out the most in the given series?

Tags: number-sequence

5, 11, 17, 23, 29, 41

Please note that I don't have an answer to this problem.

I thought of 2 possible answers,

a) 5 - it is the only single digit number in the sequence.

b) 41 - all other adjacent numbers have a difference of 6

Comment: Did you make this problem up yourself or is it from somewhere else?

Comment: I encountered it in an aptitude test.

Comment: I agree that the "find the odd one out in a  sequences" questions are open to interpretation. This question is really vague and if I have to rate it from 1 to 10 in terms of interesting-ness , I will give it 1.  Just that it was asked from me, hence I posted it here, because there was a possibility that I was missing something too obvious. Regarding the downvotes, I am no stranger to internet. :)

Comment: @rents I think there is definitely a pattern, see my answer.

Comment: @Kingrames I've noticed that you have a tendency to swear frequently in posts and comments. It's not a super serious thing, and it's not like I'm going to actively enforce it, but would it be possible for you to dial it back a little bit? Thank you!

Comment: 35 is the odd one out, 'cause it's the only number in the sequence that's not there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

29 is the odd number out because

> they're listing every other prime number starting from 5 (prime numbers from 5 to 41 are 5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41) so the sequence should have been 5,11,17,23,31,41 . 29 breaks that sequence.

Comment: This is probably the answer they're looking for IMO.

Comment: yes, this one is by far the best answer imo. But I think other answers are valid as well.

Answer (score 4):

5, 11, 17, 23, 29, 41

5 is the answer because

> it's the only single digit number.

11 is the answer because

> it contains repeating digits, which stands out amongst those numbers.

17 is the answer because

> the difference between its digits is the same difference between it and the other numbers around it.

23 is the answer because

> its digits are neighbors on the number line.

29 is the answer because

> it has the greatest difference between its digits.

41 is the answer because

> it is 12 units away from its previous neighbor in the list, rather than 6 like the others (or 5 like the first).

As you can see, each and every answer is the only true answer.

Comment: That is correct, but if you have to choose one which one will you choose (stands out THE MOST), that was what the question was in the test , the questions was single select. I understand your answer though and anyways, this might have been a question just to confuse.

Comment: Don't consider this a 100% must take serious answer. It's just an illustration of how each and every answer has a valid reason for choosing it.

Comment: 35 stands out the most because it's missing from the arithmetic sequence!

Comment: heh, that works too!

Comment: Or it is 5 because it is the only number less than 6.

Comment: Or is it the number 1, because that digit occurs 4 times among the numbers provided?

Answer (score 0):

**New answer**

When you add up the digits in each number you get:

5, 2, 8, 5, 11, 5

all of these are prime numbers except 8 (1+7), so 17 is standing out the most

**Previous answer**
 I agree with b) 41, with a slightly different reason: all numbers are a multiple of 6 followed by minus 1, (5=6-1, 11=12-1, 17=18-1 etc)

Your original answer would never allow the first number to be out of sequence.

Comment: actually 41= 42-1 as well just that we don't have 35 in this sequence. So we are saying the same thing.

Comment: missed that one,  so your reason is better